# How to smooth geom_freqpoly to exclude zeroes

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to explain violin charts to my boss, and I want to use `geom_freqpoly` so I can say "The violin chart is just a histogram flipped on its side and mirrored":

```
library(ggplot2)
df = structure(list(calc = c(0.833333333333333, 1.16666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 1.5, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 1.5, 0.833333333333333, 1.83333333333333, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.66666666666667, 1, 1.33333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 1.83333333333333, 1.16666666666667, 1.16666666666667, 1, 0.5, 1.33333333333333, 1, 0.833333333333333, 1.16666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 1.83333333333333, 1.16666666666667, 1.5, 0.833333333333333, 1.5, 1.5, 1.16666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 1, 0.833333333333333, 1.16666666666667, 1, 1, 1.33333333333333)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L), .Names = "calc")
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = calc)) + geom_violin()
ggplot(df, aes(calc)) + geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 1 / 6) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:10)
```

The problem is that the violin plot looks like this:
[image]

and the histogram looks like this:[image]

In other words, the violin plot smoothes away the zeroes but the *freqpoly* histogram does not.  **How do I make the two charts match by making *geom_freqpoly* smoothe away the zeroes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really what `geom_freqpoly` is for, it's for representing the actual frequency of each value. For smoothing, you want `geom_density`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(calc)) + 
    geom_density() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:10)
```

By default this looks to be identical to `geom_violin`, it uses the same smoothing/density estimation algorithm.

Comment: and you could add `+ coord_flip()` to illustrate the "flip and mirror".

Comment: @Marius I think I need to use both:  first `geom_freqpoly` to show him the counts, then `geom_density` as a step closer to the violin.  I accept your answer.

Comment: @neilfws Good tip, but I think my boss is capable of imagining a chart flipped on its side.